# trouble with CSS being applied to my Wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website I created, [ImASpy](http://www.imaspy.com) and the front page is fine, but the problem is when you click on "findings" all styles are completely gone from the site. I've checked my hosting account and verified that the style.css file is there and looking at the code I confirmed that the header.php is connecting to my style sheet. I really cannot figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Are there any @imports in the stylesheets using paths like `folder/css.css` or images linked like `url(images/img.png)` that might cause them not to be loaded for all paths on your site like domain.com/findings/?

Comment: yes I have img's linked like that. This is a css issue. I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: That may be why certain styles seem to be disappearing.  In your css files, paths should be relative (`/css/style.css`, `url(/images/img.png)` or relative to the css file itself (`../../images/img.png` or `./otherstyle.css`)  This way, paths work correctly if you are viewing domain.com/ or domain.com/products/category/test.  You can try firebug to see if you are getting any 404 errors that may be related too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem with your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://imaspy/wordpress/wp-content/themes/imaspy/style.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://imaspy/wordpress/xmlrpc.php" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="I&#039;m A Spy &raquo; Feed" href="http://imaspy/wordpress/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="I&#039;m A Spy &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://imaspy/wordpress/?feed=comments-rss2" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imaspy/wordpress/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imaspy/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://imaspy/wordpress/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://imaspy/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 

var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://imaspy/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/geolocation/img/wp_pin_shadow.png",
```

You need to replace http://imaspy/ with http://imaspy.com/

I think in wordpress you need to set your `Site URL` setting.

Comment: that is dynamic content generated with Wordpress's php... I have no idea how to change that. Are you sure this is the issue?

Comment: Yes, check in the admin of WP Settings->General->Site address (URL)

Comment: wow, I try to get to wp-admin and it the page doesn't open... http://www.imaspy.com/wordpress/wp-admin.php... I don't know what's going on

Comment: my whole wordpress is jacked up. I don't know where to begin

Comment: It may be that you need to change something in the database now.  It looks like you have to follow certain steps to change the site url, see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Within_Your_Site)